# WPF - two rows of tabs in a tab control - tab wrap

Tags: wpf, tabs, controls, tabcontrol

I have a WPF `TabControl` with a large number of tabs and they are presented in a sequential line all across the screen. Which means that a user needs to scroll sideways in order to view all the tabs.

Is there a way to create two rows of tabs or make the long row of tabs "wrap" into two or more rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping is the default behavior for `TabControl`s. Any `Style` or `ControlTemplate` you're using that interferes with that?

The following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

yields

[image: Window with many tabs in a tab control]

Comment: Indeed, that was the case. The enclosing grid was the problem, not the tab control. Thanx

Comment: This solution doesn’t always work — I have a window that changes its size dynamically (according to the tab item size), and I want the tabs to wrap into more rows.
Is there any way of doing it without hardcoding the width of the window/`TabControl`?

Comment: Old article: "An extended WPF tab control" https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20860/An-Extended-WPF-TabControl