# How to disable tab wrapping in the Tab Control object

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, word-wrap

I'm designing a GUI in WPF/C# and I'm using the `Tab Control` object. My `tab control` will contain a lot of tabs, and I would like to know how to disable the default "wrapping" behavior of the object. Basically the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291301/wpf-two-rows-of-tabs-in-a-tab-control-tab-wrap) question. How would I go about doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `ItemsPanel`:

```
<TabControl ....>
   <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemsPanel>
  ....
</TabControl>
```

**Edit:**

Just tested and it doesn't work. @SimonBelanger is right.

Here is a copy of the [Default Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533.aspx) of the `TabControl`, with a slight modification that changes the `TabPanel` to a Horizontal `StackPanel`:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>

      ...            
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It changes the panel for the tab content, not the tab headers.

Comment: So I have to create a separate style for this then?

Comment: @ericafterdark it would be convenient, then you can move out all the Template related XAML to a separate ResourceDictionary file or the like.

Comment: @HighCore What out of that template is absolutely essential to making this change? I'd like the code to be as minimalist as possible.

Comment: @ericafterdark only the `StackPanel`.

Comment: @HighCore when I add tabs in this style it just adds them vertically. The `tab control` is a big square now with full length tabs on the left side. I want the tabs to be on the top, and to have their wrapping feature disabled.

Comment: @EricAfterDark my XAML as pasted in this post works OK. if you remove parts of it I can't guarantee that it will work. Make sure your `StackPanel` has its `Orientation="Horizontal"` and that the `ContentPresenter` is still there where it's supposed to be.

Comment: My TabControl is in a Grid, not a StackPanel.

Why doesn't the TabControl have property to set this behaviour?