# Is there a way to determine if a WPF TabItem has a ScrollBar present?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF TabItem and sometimes there is a ScrollBar present and sometimes not. I am trying to find a way to detect if the scroll bar is present or not.

```
                    <TabItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsSelected="{Binding TabSelectedDoDads, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <TabItem.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="DoDads" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                        </TabItem.Header>
                        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <local:ucDoDadViewer x:Name="ucDoDadViewer" IsEnabled="{Binding IsDoDadViewerVisible, Converter={StaticResource bvc}}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </TabItem>
```

Comment: Where do you need to detect it? / What will you be doing with the information?

Comment: The presence of the scrollbar is causing the TabItem width to decrease and it can then cause a single tab header row to become two rows. That behavior is annoying my users. If I know if a vertical scroll bar is present then I'll be able to adjust the right margin to account for it.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794252/how-to-disable-tab-wrapping-in-the-tab-control-object

Comment: Do you know where the scrollbar is? Is it coming from your user control (ucDoDadViewer)? I ask because as far as I can tell by default a TabControl ( I assume you're using TabControl to contain your TabItem's) doesn't have a ScrollViewer around its ContentPresenter in the default ControlTemplate.

Comment: @ChrisMack, I'll take a look at your idea tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rowbear, I'll take a look at your idea tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rowbear, your questions were good and got me thinking about this better. The scrollbar is coming from one of the parent containers. The TabControl is in a UserControl which in turn has a parent. The parent has a ScrollViewer and ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility can indicate the visibility status.

Comment: I've got a fix for this. I'll answer my own question in a day or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recap of the problem and the basic components of what I ended up doing:

A UserControl sometimes had a vertical scroll bar appearing to the right, and if it did, the UserControl width shrank and caused a single tab header row to become two rows. The users did not like that behavior. So I needed to determine if a vertical scroll bar was present so that I could adjust the right margin to account for the scroll bar.

The UserControl was inside a ScrollViewer. The ScrollViewer has an event named "ScrollChanged". It seems to fire whenever the scroll bar status changes.

In the EventHandler I have this:

```
        bool isVisible = false;
        if (gridContentScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            isVisible = true;
        }
        Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(isVisible, "VerticalScrollInfoRecieved");
```

The VewModel for the UserControl is listening for the VerticalScrollInfoRecieved message. When it arrives, it updates a Margin Binding to account for the ScrollBar being visible or not.